# Is there have any way add custom CSS property value in WebStorm?

Tags: css, webstorm

WeChat app's wxss file is based on CSS. But it have custom property value like `rpx`, and `rpx` is not valid in WebStorm. So then when I reformatted the wxss file it will add a space after the number.

Just like below

```
.some_class {
    width: 100rpx;
}
```

Reformatted to

```
.some_class {
    width: 100 rpx;
}
```

and if I open the inspection it will add a red break line under `100rpx`.

Can I add custom CSS property value to let it pass the validation?

Comment: no; I can only suggest suppressing the error by adding `/*noinspection CssInvalidPropertyValue*/` above the property

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not add custom CSS property values.

You can disable `invalid CSS property value` inspection.